# Python casting and strange type convertion

Tags: python

I have a piece of code which is supposed to create and sort the list of file by their size. Here it is:

```
class DataScript(object):

def __init__(self, index, name, size):
    self.index = index
    self.name = name
    self.size = size

def __cmp__(self, other):
    if hasattr(other, 'getKey'):
        return self.getKey().__cmp__(other.getKey())

def getKey(self):
    return self.size

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    self.index += 1
    try:
        return data[self.index - 1]
    except IndexError:
        self.idx = 0
        raise StopIteration  # Done iterating.


resultList = []
data = [d for d in os.listdir(dirpath) if '_DATA_TABLE' in d]
i=0
for file in data:
    fileinfo = os.stat(join(dirpath, file))
    file_obj = DataScript(i, file, float(fileinfo.st_size))
    if isinstance(file_obj, DataScript):
        resultList.extend(file_obj)

    i=i+1

items = resultList
for i in range(len(items)):
    for j in range(len(items) - 1 - i):
        item1 = items[j]
        item2 = items[j+1]
        if isinstance(item1, DataScript) and isinstance(item2, DataScript):
            if item1.__cmp__(item2)>0:
                items[j] = item2
                items[j+1] = item1
resultList = items
```

Everything works but not exactly as expected. The result list at the end is not sorted list of DataScript objects but strings. Why ?
As an effect my sorting piece at the end doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to `append` instead of `extend`:

```
for file in data:
    fileinfo = os.stat(join(dirpath, file))
    file_obj = DataScript(i, file, float(fileinfo.st_size))
    if isinstance(file_obj, DataScript):
        resultList.append(file_obj)  # append DataScript obj to your list

    i=i+1
```

Comment: Yes, it works now but I still can't understand what's going on here. Could you put some light on it please? Why extend is casting my type on the fly to string?

Comment: `extend` takes an iterable and appends its elements to the list. When iterating over a file object, it will produce strings for each line in the file as elements, which is what you get in your `resultList`.

Comment: @kristaps it's not a file-object, it's a `DataScript` object, however, the OP implements the iterator protocol for this object, and *it returns strings*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga overlooked the type due to the variable being named `file_obj`, thanks for the correction.